# Is my custom session_start() creating an entirely new session rather than resuming the current session?

Tags: php, session, superglobals

It appears that my custom `session_start()` is creating a new session rather than resuming the current session across pages. Here's the method:

```
public function sec_session_start()
        {
            $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; //set a custom session name
            $secure = false; //set to true if using https
            $httponly = true; //This stops javascript being able to access the session id

            ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies
            $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); //Gets currtent cookies params
            session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
            session_name($session_name); //Sets the session name to the one set above
            session_start(); //Start the php session
            session_regenerate_id(true); //regernates the session, delete the old one
        }
```

The issue that I am encountering is in regard to the superglobal variable $_SESSION. For instance, in my login page I generate a random token to prevent `CSRF` attacks:

```
$token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token; //Add randomly generated token to superglobal variable
...
<input type="hidden" name="siteToken" value="$token" />
```

I then test for the correct token value in my `php` processing page:

```
//Check Token Values (prevent CSRF attacks)
    if($passedToken != $_SESSION['token']) {
        $error = "CSRF attack detected. Please close your browser and try again."; 
        $signIn->csrfAttackLog($username);
        echo $error;
        exit();     
    }
```

The problem occurs in my `php` processing page: `Notice: Undefined index: token in...`
Obviously, my session variable has not been carried over. I have started another `sec_session_start()` in the processing page - so it's not that I have neglected to continue the session. It seems that a entirely new session has been started. I have tested the first page by `"printing"` the `$_SESSION` value.

Any input is appreciated.

EDIT: `$passedToken` is correct. There is an intermediate step that equates the `$_POST` value to this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I hope I understood it right. You are trying to keep one session (with the same id, on the same cookie), just some tokens and that kind of stuff to make it more secure.
But as your last paragraph mentions, you are calling `sec_session_start();` on every page request to keep the session alive, right? But did you notice that you also call `session_regenerate_id(true);` then? That way you delete the old session files and create an entirely new session - which will be empty.

Comment: Good catch. I actually have just `session_regenerate_id()` in my current code - I dropped `true`.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply. But yes, I wound up going through all my code. I actually found that my Master Class was trying to include that function. It is odd since that class has no need for that file - I don't know why it was there. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

see in the form you have `name="siteToken"` but in condition `if($passedToken !=`. I suppose should be `if($siteToken !=`. Also try to calls `sec_session_start` before `if`

Comment: I was considering editing my post. There is an intermediate step: I took the `$_POST` value that was passed and equated it to `$passedToken`.

Comment: Directly before `if`? I called it sooner than that because I am writing and "echoing" variables before that point.

Comment: Did you try that : sec_session_start(); if($passedToken != $_SESSION['token']){

Comment: Yes, I just did. Unfortunately that didn't work. I'm rather stumped.

Comment: then to make sure sec_session_start();$token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

Comment: Let's go this route. Does session start have to be the ABSOLUTELY first line of code? As I have it set up now, I call its containing class and generate the local `$token` value fist (That part is an external file). Could this be the issue? However, I don't save the `$token` to `$_SESSION` UNTIL the `session_start()` has been executed. I removed my custom method and simply used `session_start()`. The same issue is occuring.